# Can a byte/word inserted as an entry in a Feistel S-box be breakable?

Tags: s-boxes, feistel-network

Let's suppose I insert these two 4-byte words (32-bits) in a feistel S-box with 1024-bytes of size (256*32-bits), (like Blowfish does):

**blah** **bleh**

What kind of attacks could possible be made to discover the words faster than brute-forcing the entire S-box (if they exist)?

Does inserting words/bytes in feistel S-boxes have a formula or a reverse operation for recovering the words/bytes without discovering the entire S-box?

Comment: Can adversaries experiment with known key/plaintext? The context in which the S-box is used matters. Things like how the S-box is used to build the Feistel round, width of the block cipher, number of rounds...

Comment: May I ask how the question arises? This feels like it might be a CTF.